# Validate email regex with invalid characters using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email

I found this Regex in stack overflow for the email validation but this regex won't validate the invalid characters in the email. 
I couldn't find a proper answer to it.

If the email is Vinu'a@gmail.com this gives as a valid email address.

```
var patternForEmailValidation = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
var patternForEmailValidation = patternForEmailValidation.test(email);
```

Comment: you want only alpha and digit??

Comment: yes, all the invalid characters should be validated in a email addy . !#$%&*()

Comment: dose those domains contain  these characters ? ( '"!#$%&^*)

Comment: Probably not (in international domains), but they certainly are not 'ascii' characters. Also: `Vinu*a@gmail.com` **is** a perfectly valid mail-address.. might not be to google, but since when do they make the rules `:)` There won't be a lot of people burning their fingers on this futile exercise.

Comment: but shouldn't we have to consider ' ? above regex won't validate that also :(

Comment: Nope we shouldn't. We should accept whatever the user feeds us and send the confirmation mail already!

Comment: if I have something like vinu'@gmail.com , it will break in the server side is it not possible to handle those ?

Comment: Then.. like any input, you'd escape it, otherwise messing up your database would be loads-o-fun to some! (Pretty much the only thing to check on is the existence of an @ sign and at least one dot. All the rest is futile (well, it was before but now (international urls and tld-domains) it really is).

Comment: @GitaarLAB: I don't think there is a need to escape the input if the db application is done properly with prepared statement.

Answer (score -1):

Try following regex

```
var em_regex =  /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
```

Comment: I have used this expression at many places, but I did not find any issues till now. @GitaarLAB, can you give me any example where it can be failed, so that I can make corrections.

Comment: @GitaarLAB, I just tried the example you have specified. But in my case it validated the email and shown me the error.

Comment: Ok, I see I missed the `\.` hei@やる.ca would indeed work, my bad for that, sorry. But it does fail for `email@-example.com`, or `Abc..123@example.com`, `email@[123.123.123.123]`, granted tough, it is better than I thought at first, I'll remove my first comment, that's to harsh.

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html (mind you, also not perfect..), Oh, and here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/78353/how-far-should-one-take-e-mail-address-validation

Comment: Icing on the cake: http://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/588079 and other answers there.